# in a Vagrantfile, I define a local variable. How can pass it to a bash script as a parameter? $var, #var, #{var}?

Tags: ruby, bash, vagrant, vagrantfile

In a *Vagrantfile*, I want to run scripts.
But some part of them shouldn't run in provision mode.

I've sat a local variable `update = "true"` (or false) depending of the value of the *Vagrant* command.

A `puts` shows me that it is valued by `"false"`, by example,
but then, I'm unable to send its content to a bash script, for parameter.

I've tried `$update`, `#update`, `#{update}`, `update` without success
on the line `bash common/300_Kafka.sh "3.4.0" "2.12" $update`

Part of the Vagrantfile:

```rb
if ARGV[0] == "provision"
  update = "true"
else
  update = "false"
end

puts "Vagrant box. Démarrage en mode mise à jour : " + update

config.vm.provision "file", source: "../common", destination: "common"

config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
  bash common/050_Certificats.sh
  bash common/070_Utilitaires.sh
  bash common/100_JDK.sh "17"
  bash common/150_Postgresql-Postgis.sh "15" "3" "postgres"
  bash common/200_NodeJS-Angular.sh "16"
  bash common/250_ELK.sh "7.x"
  bash common/300_Kafka.sh "3.4.0" "2.12" $update
SHELL
```

Message on console:

```
Vagrant box. Démarrage en mode mise à jour : false

default: Indiquez si Kafka est en installation initiale (false) ou update (true).  n'est pas accepté.
```

The bash script called, testing the values:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# $1: Version de Kafka [3.4.0]
# $2: Version de Scala associée [2.12]
# $3: Mode update (true) ou installation initiale (false)
echo "300 : Installation de Kafka $1 basé sur Scala $2"
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Précisez la version de Kafka à installer. [Recommandée : 3.4.0]" >&2;
  exit 1;
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
  echo "Précisez la version de Scala liée. [Recommandée : 2.12]" >&2;
  exit 1;
fi

if [ "$3" != "true" ] && [ "$3" != "false" ]; then
  echo "Indiquez si Kafka est en installation initiale (false) ou update (true). $3 n'est pas accepté." >&2;
  exit 1;
fi

update=$3

if [ "$update" == "false" ]; then
   cd /tmp && wget -q "https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/$1/kafka_$2-$1.tgz"
   sudo tar -xf "kafka_$2-$1.tgz" -C /opt
   echo "export KAFKA_HOME=/opt/kafka_$2-$1" >> ~/.profile
else
   echo "En mode update, Kafka ne se réinstallera pas."
fi
```

Comment: What error message do you get when using `#{update}`?

Comment: @Stefan `  n'est pas accepté`. The parameter value isn't sent.

Comment: Intrinsic functionality for this: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/triggers

Comment: @MattSchuchard I don't see how I would use it?

Answer (score 3):

My way of sending parameters to shell script isn't correct.
It looks working but doesn't perfectly, inside of an `inline <<-SHELL`.

I found myself successful with that, instead:

```rb
if ARGV[0] == "provision"
  update = "true"
else
  update = "false"
end

puts "Vagrant box. Démarrage en mode mise à jour : " + update

config.vm.provision "file", source: "../common", destination: "common"

config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "../common/050_Certificats.sh"
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "../common/070_Utilitaires.sh"
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "../common/100_JDK.sh", args: ["17"]
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "../common/150_Postgresql-Postgis.sh", args: ["15", "3", "postgres"]
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "../common/200_NodeJS-Angular.sh", args: ["16"]
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "../common/250_ELK.sh", args: ["7.x"]
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "../common/300_Kafka.sh", args: ["3.4.0", "2.12", "#{update}"]
```

Comment: In this case, the interpolation is superfluous.

Comment: You should be able to do an even simpler form like `update = (ARGV[0] == "provision").to_s`

Comment: You don't need the interpolation in `["3.4.0", "2.12", "#{update}"]`, simply `["3.4.0", "2.12", update]` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
bash common/300_Kafka.sh "3.4.0" "2.12" "#{update}"
```

because from the error message it seems like it explicitly expects the string `"true"` or `"false"`.

Comment: Regarding shell script arguments, `script "true"` is equivalent to `script true`. Quotes are used to allow whitespace in argument values, not to indicate strings (shell script arguments are always strings).

Comment: If I attempt something like this: `bash common/300_Kafka.sh "3.4.0" "2.12" #{update}`, removing the quotes around `"#{update}"`, the _Vagrantfile_ becomes invalid.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan does it work when using a literal value without quotes, e.g. `bash common/300_Kafka.sh "3.4.0" "2.12" true`?